# doctrine dbal get latest chat message per group

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, greatest-n-per-group, slim

when trying make multiple select

```
$result = $this->qb->select('c.id','c.message','acc.name as chat_from', 'c.chat_to as count')
    ->addSelect("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY date_deliver DESC")
        ->from($this->table,'c')
        ->join('c','account','acc', 'c.chat_from = acc.id')
        ->orderBy('date_sent','DESC')
        ->groupby('chat_from')
        ->where('chat_to ='.$id)
        ->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll();
```

i also tried

```
$result = $this->qb->select('c.id','c.message','acc.name as chat_from', 'c.chat_to as count')
        ->from("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY date_deliver DESC",'c')
        ->join('c','account','acc', 'c.chat_from = acc.id')
        ->orderBy('date_sent','DESC')
        ->groupby('chat_from')
        ->where('chat_to ='.$id)
        ->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll();
```

I want to display the data by group by and then display the data inside the last entry.

i' used DOCTRINE DBAL

Comment: Any error your are getting from above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is unclear so i am assuming you need to get the recent chat/message per group, the equivalent SQL for this will be

```
 SELECT c.id, c.message, a.name as chat_from, c.chat_to as count
 FROM account a
 JOIN chat c ON(c.chat_from = a.id )
 LEFT JOIN chat cc ON(c.chat_from = cc.chat_from AND c.date_sent < cc.date_sent)
 WHERE cc.date_sent IS NULL AND c.chat_to = @id
 ORDER BY c.date_sent DESC
```

So using doctrine dbal you can write above query as

```
$this->qb->select( 'c.id', 'c.message', 'a.name as chat_from', 'c.chat_to as count' )
         ->from( 'account', 'a' )
         ->join( 'a', 'chat', 'c', 'c.chat_from = a.id' )
         ->leftJoin( 'c', 'chat', 'cc', 'c.chat_from = cc.chat_from AND c.date_sent < cc.date_sent' )
         ->where( 'cc.date_sent IS NULL' )
         ->andWhere( 'c.chat_to =' . $id )
         ->orderBy( 'c.date_sent', 'DESC' )
         ->execute();
```

Again without viewing the sample data and DDL its not a complete solution.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group/46233080#46233080)