# Symfony Doctrine take the most recent object result : Having clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to get the recent document from my database, I have created this `queryBuilder` to get the Document `obeject` but it seems not working good when I add the clause `Having`.
This my query:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('sm');

    $qb
        ->andWhere('sm.supplier = :supplier')
        ->setParameter('supplier', $supplierId)
        ->andHaving('MAX(sm.createdAt)')
        ->groupBy('sm.id');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

And this is the exception I'm getting:

> {"code":500,"message":"[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected
>   =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string."}

This my `DQL`:

`"SELECT sm FROM SupplierBundle\\Entity\\SupplierMedia sm WHERE sm.supplier = :supplier AND sm.type = :type GROUP BY sm.id HAVING MAX(sm.createdAt)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` expression defines conditions that will be applied on the result set after `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

If you just need to get last record from a table apply limit and order by.

Comment: ->setMaxResults(1); youmean by limit ?

Comment: It gives me the oldest element nit the recent

Comment: Well, just change `order by` direction, like `->orderBy('a.createdAt DESC')`

Comment: This is the right syntaxe bro `orderBy('sm.createdAt', 'DESC')` any way thank you forr help :)I really appreciate good idea (y)

Answer (score 1):

To get the recent object for each supplier you could go with a self join approach

```
SELECT a 
FROM  SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierMedia a
    LEFT JOIN SupplierBundle\Entity\SupplierMedia b 
    WITH a.supplier = b.supplier 
    AND a.createdAt < b.createdAt
WHERE b.createdAt IS NULL
AND a.supplier = :supplier 
AND a.type = :type
```

[**Doctrine Query Language get Max/Latest Row Per Group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group/46233080#46233080)

Comment: @ahmedbhs Its DQL already, if you want to the query builder version you follow the reference link [**Doctrine Query Language get Max/Latest Row Per Group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group/46233080#46233080)