# Doctrine query builder , select last record of group by , but always returns the first one

Tags: doctrine, query-builder, symfony4

I'm using symfony4 and doctrine2. In the table I have some data have the same startDate.

I'd like to select all data in this table but group by startDate and the last one.
For example if I have 3 records have the start date 2018-02-01, so I'd like to select the last one added.

This is the query builder in the repository but the problem is that the first record is selected not the last despite that I added ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC') as you can see.

Let's say that I have this lines:

```
id = 1 , startDay = 2017-04-20

id = 2, startDay = 2018-01-02

id = 3, startDay = 2018-03-18

id = 4 , startDay = 2018-01-02
```

So the lines with ids  1, 3 and 4 should be selected from table. Line with id 2 must be ignored because it has the same startDate of line 4.
But my query returns ligne 2 not 4.

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->groupBy('e.startDate')
        ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So if many of records have the same startDate so select the last one added

Comment: I don't understand, you want to select all records with starting date whatever and order them DESC by id, or you want to select just the last 1 added from all with starting date whatever ?

Comment: @Angel,  I'd like to all records and if many of them have the same startDate so select the last one added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine Query Language get Max/Latest Row Per Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group)