# How to use GROUP_BY with a query builder and mySQL >= 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

After migrating my database to CloudDB with Mysql 5.7 version I have problem with query builder in symfony 4.

The following code works great with mysql 5.6

```
public function findRecentReviews($max): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->andWhere('r.active = :active')
        ->setParameter('active', 1)
        ->setMaxResults($max)
        ->groupBy('r.website')
        ->orderBy('r.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
}
```

With 5.7 I'm getting this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An >exception occurred while executing 'SELECT r0_.id AS id_0, r0_.comment AS >comment_1, r0_.author AS author_2, r0_.email AS email_3, r0_.added AS >added_4, r0_.ip AS ip_5, r0_.active AS active_6, r0_.hide_in_latest AS >hide_in_latest_7, r0_.rate AS rate_8, r0_.website_id AS website_id_9 FROM >review r0_ WHERE r0_.active = ? GROUP BY r0_.website_id ORDER BY r0_.id ASC >LIMIT 3' with params [1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of >SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column >'ps_main.r0_.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY >clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by").*

I can't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode because I don't have a superuser privileges.

How should look like my query if I can't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and I can't downgrade a mysql version?

Comment: Why are you currently using group by? I don't see any aggregated columns. Are you just using it to get a distinct list of websites?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the name of the function previously. Looks like the group by is there so you'll only get one review for each website?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, yes. I need only one review for each website.

Comment: I think this looks like a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem. This Q&A may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46106582/doctrine-query-language-get-max-latest-row-per-group

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [MySQL Handling of Group By](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence.

If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the `select list`, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the `GROUP BY` clause nor are functionally dependent on them.

There are two options.

1: Disable SQL mode `only_full_group_by`: You can check this by executing below query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%';

Output:
sql_mode     'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'
```

**Disable `only_full_group_by` in mysql** by removing `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from `sql_mode` variable.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

2: Update your query:

```
SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;
```

Reference: [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: OP states in the question that they can't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Are they mistaken? If so, can you explain why? I'm not meaning to be critical, I'm just curious.

Comment: Unfortunetly, like I said I can't change this beucase I don't have superuser priviliges. I'm getting "42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation" so the only solution is to change my query in doctrine.

Comment: @Szymon  every user can alter the session thread values including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` the `SET SESSION` one should work the `GLOBAL` indeed requires `SUPER` priv.. But i advice to fix the query

Comment: Keep in mind that `SELECT name, ANY_VALUE(address), MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;` more or less runs like (extreme example) in the optimizer as `SELECT name, (SELECT address FROM t t_inner WHERE t_inner.name = t.name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS 'ANY_VALUE(address)', MAX(age) FROM t GROUP BY name;` .. i would advice more that the topicstarter would fix the query..

Comment: I think, that I can't use ANY_VALUE in doctrine query builder. Maybe I will use a pure SQL query Instead.