# Symfony Query Builder (Subquery)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, greatest-n-per-group, query-builder

How would this SQL query look in the Query Builder? Unfortunately, subselects are not possible, right?

SQL:

```
SELECT t.* FROM domain_check_result AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, MAX(checkDate) AS MaxDate
FROM domain_check_result
GROUP BY domain_id) AS tm ON t.domain_id = tm.domain_id AND t.checkDate = tm.MaxDate
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

To pick latest result from your group (domains) you can rewrite your query as below and it would be easier to translate this query in DQL and query builder

SQL

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM
  domain_check_result a 
  LEFT JOIN domain_check_result b 
    ON a.domain_id = b.domain_id 
    AND a.checkDate < b.checkDate 
WHERE b.checkDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY a.checkDate DESC
```

DQL

```
SELECT a 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\DomainCheckResult a
    LEFT JOIN AppBundle\Entity\DomainCheckResult b 
    WITH a.domain = b.domain 
    AND a.checkDate < b.checkDate
WHERE b.checkDate IS NULL
ORDER BY a.checkDate DESC
```

And in query you could translate your DQL as

```
$repo = $DM->getRepository( 'AppBundle\Entity\DomainCheckResult' );
$results = $repo->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
                ->select( 'a' )
                ->leftJoin(
                    'AppBundle\Entity\DomainCheckResult',
                    'b',
                    'WITH',
                    'a.domain = b.domain AND a.checkDate < b.checkDate'
                )
                ->where( 'b.checkDate IS NULL' )
                ->orderBy( 'a.checkDate','DESC' )
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

[**Reference: Doctrine Query Language get Max/Latest Row Per Group**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46233080/853360)